# I have a VBA code that split string in to a separate columns based on a space separator. I need to write each single word to every second column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a VBA code that split string in a column in to a separate columns based on a space separator. I need to write each single word to every second column. It means 1st word in column D, next word in column F, H ..... how can I modify my entire code? thank you

```
Sub SplitBySemicolonExample()
    'Define variables
    Dim MyArray() As String, MyString As String, i As Variant, N As Integer, x As Long, NumRows As Long
    NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    For x = 2 To NumRows + 1
    'Sample string with semi colon delimiters
    MyString = Cells(x, 3).Value
    
    'Use Split function to divide up the component parts of the string
    MyArray = Split(MyString, " ")
    
    'Clear the worksheet
    'ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Clear
    
    'iterate through the array
    
    
    For N = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
        
        Cells(x, N + 4).Value = MyArray(N)
        
    Next N
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next way:

```
Sub splitBySpace()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, splRng As Range
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Set splRng = ws.Range("B2", ws.Range("B" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp))
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   splRng.Replace " ", "  ", xlPart 'replace a space with two
   'Change Destination to be "D2" (ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False):
   splRng.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
           ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, space:=True, Other:=False
   splRng.Replace "  ", " ", xlPart 'replace the double spaces with simple ones
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, But I maybe not explained the issue so precised. The code works for me all is fine. But I have proble with writing the value in every second column. I am not able to define that each second column will be with occupied with string and column between will be empty. Like D2- string1; E2-empty cell; F2-string2; G2 empty cell... like this

Comment: @Michal Balek Reading your question in the light of the above comment, you are right. I will adapt the above code in a minute...

Answer (score 0):

sticking to your code, just use:

```
Cells(x, 2 * N + 4).Value = MyArray(N)
```

while, refactoring your entire code in a more coincise style:

```
Sub SplitEverySecondColumn()
  With Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="  ", LookAt:=xlPart ' let's "double" the space delimiter

    .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                   Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False ' ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False makes consider each single space as a delimiter -> skipping one column
    End With
End Sub
```

where: